# Win32 API Method

Tags: winapi

Win32 API Method `SetProcessWorkingSetSize(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1)` is thread-safe or not?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean thread-*safe*? If so, yes, I believe it is.

Comment: yes i meant thread-safe. If you ve specific reason, please post me. Thank You

Comment: @rabin: Yes, it's thread-safe because, as far as I know, all such functions that call kernel-mode functions like [NtSetInformationProcess](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Process/NtSetInformationProcess.html) are synchronized across the entire system.

Answer (score 0):

`SetProcessWorkingSetSize` is threadsafe. The setting are done at the process level and are thread safe.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your claim?

Comment: MSDN documentation says the same: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686234(v=vs.85).aspx and its related pages